# What is the meaning of using the past simple for actions that continue to the present?

Tags: meaning, tense, past-simple

Are these sentences correct

> I **have loved** you since I **knew** you [since (a point of time)]

means I'm still in love or very recently broke up. But what does

> I **loved** you since I **knew** you [since (a point of time)]

mean? The use of the past simple indicates a "finished" action so I don't understand this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence should be:

> I have loved you [ever] since I met you.

Knowing someone continues indefinitely. By contrast, meeting someone takes place at a specific point in time, which is what you want to express.

This sentence is not correct:

> I loved you [ever] since I met you.

but you might hear it in careless speech.

Answer (score -1):

The first phrase looks right. We use the present perfect to talk about things in continuing state. For example :

> My professor has loved math since he is eight.

By the way, if you would like to exprime an idea of break up, you should used the simple past that exprime a finished action. 
In this case your phrase means that you still love her.

I have an idea about the second phrase but it might be wrong.

> I loved you since I knew you

Means "I like you from the first time we met".

Comment: Those are not right. You cannot say the first because the *is* is wrong, and you cannot say the second because *know* does not mean *met* in English.

Comment: Ok, at least I tried.

Comment: You can correct "is" to "since the age of eight" and the second sentence can be "I love you as long as I know you" or "I have loved you since the time I met you".