# I loved you because I knew you: still in love?

Tags: meaning-in-context

When I say:

> *I loved you because I knew you*

does it give any information on how I feel about this person now?

If I am still in love or not because *I loved* (past simple) is in the past, so we can understand that the person is not in love now. Am I right or not?

Comment: "I loved you because I knew you" is a bit of an odd phrase. If you want to convey that the person was so wonderful that you only had to know them in order to love them, I've heard "to know him is to love him", but never "to know you is to love you". You might also use "I've loved you ever since I met you". "I loved you because I knew you" gives the impression of a love which is now over, yes, but the phrase is strange.

Comment: possible duplicate: [What is the meaning of using the past simple for actions that continue to the present?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/69313/22894)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Patrick – your example sentence is rather odd, and a bit tough to analyze.

However, to answer the root of your question, it *is* possible to use a verb in the simple past without necessarily implying that a feeling is no longer there. However, I think it's a bit unusual to use the simple past like that without offering further information in the sentence.

For example, if my wife was going through chemotherapy five years ago, I might say:

> I loved you when you had no hair.

and that wouldn't necessarily mean I don't still love her now. However, there's a good chance I would change the wording a bit to make my intent a bit clearer:

> I loved you *even* when you had no hair.

---

Here's another example: let's say my wife would dye her hair purple when she was younger, and that is what first caught my eye. I could say:

> I loved you because of your purple hair.

and she might reply:

> What? Does that mean you don't love me anymore?

So, I could be a bit more specific, and say:

> I *fell in love with you* because of your purple hair.

That small modification points the sentence more toward my initial attraction to her, not my current feelings about her, which is the real focus. Still, the initial sentence could work just fine in the right context:

> **She**: Why did you fall in love with me, anyway?
>   **He**: I loved you because of your purple hair.

Answer (score 1):

Since it only describes the past, it *implies* that the loving has stopped, but it doesn't say that explicitly; it is ambiguous about the present.

Comment: True. Just because you loved someone in the past doesn't mean you don't love them any longer in the present.